# Alert Box | Back Ground Color Status bar & Navigation Bar Color | in Flutter How to change

Tags: flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout

I am Working on Flutter App Were i show Dialog Box to user For User Input But When Dialog box is show the background color of dialog box can'not applied in **status bar** and **navigation bar** how to solve this ??

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: please provide the final result image.